# Django channels websocket.receive is not handled

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I'm trying to implement Django channels going through the docs.
So like the docs i'm making `consumers.py`

```
def ws_message(message):
    message.reply_channel.send({
        "text": message.content['text'],
})
```

and `routing.py` as

```
from channels.routing import route
from my_proj.consumers import ws_message

channel_routing = [
    route("websocket.receive", ws_message),
]
```

In my `settings` file I added `channel_layers`

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("localhost", 6379)],
        },
        "ROUTING": "my_proj.routing.channel_routing",
    },
}
```

So when I runserver and in chrome console send the following

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + 192.168.4.177:8000");
socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    alert(e.data);
}
socket.onopen = function() {
    socket.send("something");
}
```

I can see in manage.py console that Websocket connect worked and the connection is established, but the `receive` part is not handled and is not seen in console so alert from js code is not raised. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @UtkarshSinha this has no effect. Again i can see the connect but not the receive.

Comment: Try  sending the data in JSON format. I think it's probably not being able to pick 'text' from the message, like so:   socket.send(JSON.stringify({"text": "something"}));

Comment: @UtkarshSinha I tried, again no luck. To mention again. I dont think it is a problem of picking 'text' (mainly because the example is from Channels docs). You see, in a console of `manage.py runworker v2` I do not see ``runworker - websocket.receive`` debugging msg. Meansing the send does not reach to the consumer.

Comment: @UtkarshSinha When i try what i described in question in an empty app it works. But I try in a real application this doesnt work. Is it possible that something in my settings.py file blocks ``receive``?

Comment: Not really, because your websocket.connect is working.

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error - a Missing quote in socket JS write before the ip-address. Correct it to:  socket = new WebSocket("ws://" +  "192.168.4.177:8000");   You might also try without the port.

Comment: @UtkarshSinha again the same result.

Comment: Your code seems fine so far. Would need more information to figure this out. 1. Run Google Dev Tools (Network>WS>check if Websocket is opened by JS) > check if your frame is sent 2. In parallel > Run 'python manage.py runworker' (live console) > Check if it begins with "Listening on channels websocket.receive, websocket.connect, http.request, websocket.disconnect" > Check if it throws an error when message is sent (Please post error if any) 3. Check if you have asgi_redis installed properly and whether you have asgi.py in your Project folder next to settings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117098/discussion-between-arminrock-and-utkarsh-sinha).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was with the version of Twisted. By now the latest version of it is 16.3.0 but the Channels require 16.2.0 version. So with 16.2.0 version of Twisted it works as should.

Comment: Lost 2h of my life on this problem, I downgraded to 16.2.0 and it started working. So thanks a lot for sharing the answer !

Comment: Saved my day! Thanks a lot :)